# Powershell - Force local users to change password on next login

Tags: powershell, security, passwords

I was hoping someone could help.

I need to somehow force local users to change passwords on the first of every month.

I've looked at PS and not found a way to set this flag.
Nor a way of adding this into GPO via PS.

If someone who is a PS guru can help I'd be very appreciative.

Cheers CM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED!!

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2089854-script-to-create-local-users-on-workstation

As per the above link we can change its expiry to true and next time user must change the password

```
$expUser = [ADSI]"WinNT://localhost/$user,user"
$expUser.passwordExpired = 1
$expUser.setinfo()
```

The user 'USER' will asked to change the password

Comment: Hi Kamel, that I am guessing is for an AD account a local account - and had seen that exact line in other posts - and does not work.  Thanks all the same.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the LOCAL word.